# Populating each ListItem from multiple tables using CursorAdapter

Tags: android, database, relational-database, android-cursoradapter

I have two tables `LectureTimeTable` and `LectureDayTable` the structure of these tables is as follows:
`_ID | start_time | end_time | location | course_ID_FK` and `_ID | class_Day | classTime_ID_FK | course_ID_FK` respectively, and i am creating these tables as follows:

**Creating LectureTimeTable:**

```
public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_CLASS_START_TIME = "startTime";
public static final String COL_CLASS_END_TIME = "endTime";
public static final String COL_CLASS_LOCATION = "loc";
public static final String COL_COURSE_ID_FK = "cls_main_CourseId_fk";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "lectureTimeTable";

// query for creating the TABLE_CLASS_DAYS_MAIN table.
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER, " + COL_CLASS_START_TIME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_CLASS_END_TIME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COL_CLASS_LOCATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COL_COURSE_ID_FK
        + " INTEGER, " + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_COURSE_ID_FK
        + ") REFERENCES " + Course.TABLE_NAME + " (" + Course._ID + "), "
        + " PRIMARY KEY (" + _ID + ", " + COL_COURSE_ID_FK + "));";
```

**Creating LectureDayTable:**

```
public static final String _ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_CLASS_DAY = "classDay";
public static final String COL_CLASS_TIME_ID_FK = "classTime_id_fk";
public static final String COL_COURSE_ID_FK = "course_id_fk";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "LectureDayTable";

// query for creating the TABLE_CLASS_DAYS_MAIN table.
public static final String TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
        + " (" + _ID + " INTEGER, " + COL_CLASS_DAY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COL_CLASS_TIME_ID_FK + " INTEGER, " + COL_COURSE_ID_FK
        + " INTEGER, " + "FOREIGN KEY (" + COL_COURSE_ID_FK + ", "
        + COL_CLASS_TIME_ID_FK + ") REFERENCES "
        + CourseLectureTime.TABLE_NAME + " ("
        + CourseLectureTime.COL_COURSE_ID_FK + ", " + CourseLectureTime._ID
        + "), " + "PRIMARY KEY (" + _ID + ", " + COL_CLASS_TIME_ID_FK
        + ", " + COL_COURSE_ID_FK + "));";
```

Now i am showing this information in the ListFragment where i am showing schedule for a Course in which i have designed `ListItem` as shown in the picture 
 in which i am showing the `Location(in the picture bellow "se")`, `start_time`, and `end_time` from the `LectureTimeTable` and for that time i am showing all `days` from the `LectureDayTable(in the following picture "Su" and "Mo")`

[image: Llist Item of the ListFragment]

I don't know whether my approach is bad or not but i have done to do so by the following code of `CursorAdapter`:

```
public class ScheduleListAdapter2 extends CursorAdapter {
private TextView classLocationTV;
private TextView classTimeTV;
private TextView sundayTV;
private TextView mondayTV;
private TextView tuesdayTV;
private TextView wednesdayTV;
private TextView thursdayTV;
private TextView fridayTV;
private TextView saturdayTV;
private ContentResolver mContentResolver;

private long timeID = 0;
private long courseId;
private AsyncQueryHandler mAsyncQueryHandler;
private Context context;

public ScheduleListAdapter2(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery,
        ContentResolver cr, long courseID) {
    super(context, c, autoRequery);
    mContentResolver = cr;
    this.courseId = courseID;
    this.context = context;
    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG,
            "--------------- ScheduleListAdapter constructor called-------------------");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor mCursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first tim*e,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_schedule, parent,
            false);

    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG,
            "--------------- ScheduleListAdapter newView called-------------------");
    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor mCursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG,
            "--------------- ScheduleListAdapter bindView called-------------------");

    classLocationTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locationTV);
    classLocationTV.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(CourseLectureTime.COL_CLASS_LOCATION)));

    classTimeTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lectureTimeTV);
    classTimeTV.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor
            .getColumnIndex(CourseLectureTime.COL_CLASS_START_TIME))
            + "-"
            + mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(CourseLectureTime.COL_CLASS_END_TIME)));

    timeID = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(CourseLectureTime._ID));
    Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG, "--------------- GOT THE TIME ID: " + timeID);

    sundayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sundayTV);
    mondayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mondayTV);
    tuesdayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tuesdayTV);
    wednesdayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wednesdayTV);
    thursdayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.thursdayTV);
    fridayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fridayTV);
    saturdayTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.saturdayTV);

    mAsyncQueryHandler = new AsyncQueryHandler(mContentResolver) {

        private long mDay;

        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie,
                Cursor cursor) {
            super.onQueryComplete(token, cookie, cursor);

            Log.i(MyConstants.LOG_TAG,
                    "Returned lecture days: " + cursor.getCount());

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                mDay = cursor.getLong(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(CourseLectureDay.COL_CLASS_DAY));

                if (mDay == 0) {
                    sundayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    sundayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                } else if (mDay == 1) {
                    mondayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    mondayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                } else if (mDay == 2) {
                    tuesdayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    tuesdayTV
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                } else if (mDay == 3) {
                    wednesdayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    wednesdayTV
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                } else if (mDay == 4) {
                    thursdayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    thursdayTV
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                } else if (mDay == 5) {
                    fridayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    fridayTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                } else if (mDay == 6) {
                    saturdayTV.setTextAppearance(
                            ScheduleListAdapter2.this.context,
                            R.style.enabledDayStyle);
                    saturdayTV
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled_day_background);
                }

            }

        }
    };

    mAsyncQueryHandler
            .startQuery(
                    1,
                    new Object(),
                    CourseLectureDay.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { CourseLectureDay.COL_CLASS_DAY },
                    CourseLectureDay.COL_CLASS_TIME_ID_FK + " = ? AND "
                            + CourseLectureDay.COL_COURSE_ID_FK + " = ? ",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(timeID),
                            String.valueOf(courseId) }, null);

    }
}
```

The Add a Schedule by giving the **Room Location**, **Start Time**, **End Time**, and **days of the week** i.e, Monday, Tuesday, etc. (*Please Suggest me if you have better idea than that*)

The **Problem** is that it some time does not show the correct days in the `ListItem` or show the last ListItem's days in the FirstList item. I don't know what i am doing wrong here and please suggest me better way to achieve this:

Thanks

Comment: why dont you use SimpleCursorAdapter and CursorLoader?

Comment: Becuase `SimpleCursorAdapter` cannot be used for designing complex list items.

Comment: what do you mean "complex list items"?

Comment: That i have shown in the Picture above in question in which it consists of 9 `TextView`s

Comment: did you use SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder?

Comment: No. As you can see that my `ScheduleAdapter2` class is extending `CursorAdapter`

Comment: thats why i asked why not to use SimpleCursorAdapter